# Dynamically setting ColumnSpan on a GridView intermittently breaks layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView whereby columns are shown/hidden based on a user's CheckBox selections.  When the GridView is rendered, the first row of text needs to span multiple columns.  The gridview is generated outside my control, and the number of numeric columns is dynamic, so I can only set visibilities after the gridview is data bound.  Because of the dynamic number of numeric columns, I cannot iterate backwards through the column collection because I never know how many columns there'll be.

When showing **all** columns it works well:

[image]

When showing **no** columns, it works well:

[image]

When showing a **single** column, it breaks:

[image]

Can somebody please correct my flawed logic and explain why my approach doesn't work?  I believe that the issue is how I am removing cells from the row to match the column span value.

```
protected void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // reset from previous postback
    gv.Columns[2].Visible = true;
    gv.Columns[3].Visible = true;

    CreateGridView();

    gv.Columns[2].Visible = ShowFoo.Checked;
    gv.Columns[3].Visible = ShowBar.Checked;
        
    int colSpan = 2; // Span FirstName + Surname columns
    colSpan += ShowFoo.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    colSpan += ShowBar.Checked ? 1 : 0;

    for(int c = 1; c <= colSpan - 1; c++) // 1 = Leaving the first cell so the cell text value is preserved
    {
        gv.Rows[0].Cells.RemoveAt(1); // remove the second cell each time to reduce the cell collection
    }

    gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = colSpan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out using a static approach; referring to each column index manually based on the respective checkbox setting.  Not the most glamorous solution but it works.  If you have a better solution then please contribute.

```
protected void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // reset from previous postback
    gv.Columns[2].Visible = true;
    gv.Columns[3].Visible = true;

    CreateGridView();

    gv.Columns[2].Visible = ShowFoo.Checked;
    gv.Columns[3].Visible = ShowBar.Checked;

    // Calculate column span

    int colSpan = 2; // Span FirstName + Surname columns
    colSpan += ShowFoo.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    colSpan += ShowBar.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = colSpan;

    // Remove cells (last-to-first to preserve cell indexes)

    if (ShowBar.Checked) { gv.Rows[0].Cells.RemoveAt(3); } // Remove Bar column
    if (ShowFoo.Checked) { gv.Rows[0].Cells.RemoveAt(2); } // Remove Foo column
    gv.Rows[0].Cells.RemoveAt(1); // Remove Surname column

}
```